# NGINX dynamic path returning 404

Tags: nginx

i have nginx running locally and am trying to create a simple dynamic path location.

The location block is:

```
 location ~ ^/users/(.+)$/roles {

  return 200;

  }
```

After running, I try to hit the endpoint

> http://localhost:80/users/1/roles

But I end up with a 404.

If I change the location block to:

```
 location /users/1/roles {

  return 200;

  }
```

I get a 200 and everything works just find.  I have been pulling my hair out over this because it seems so simple that I thought a ton of documentation would exist about this. But I can not find a solution, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have a spurious `$` in your regular expression. The `$` is used to anchor the end of a regular expression.

Comment: Thanks, but removing that does not fix it.